# JavaScript call functions that does not exist in an immediate environment

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I saw [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) a way of calling a method that does not immediately exist in the JavaScript environment.

Let me do the explanation.

Here is the server-side code,

```
public class ContosoChatHub : Hub
{
    public void NewContosoChatMessage(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.addContosoChatMessageToPage(name, message);
    }
}
```

Client invokes the `NewContosoChatMessage` method from client side using JavaScript like this

```
server.newContosoChatMessage($('#displayname').val(), $('#message').val());
```

From what I know client side does not know the existance of the method `NewContosoChatMessage` in the Server. So my guess is that the function that is being invoked on `server` object can be acquired as a string and pass it to server.

If this is possible I can make one of my tasks that I'm currently working on much more elegant.

How can I get this done?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean: `newContosoChatMessage` is a method on the client proxy, so it does exist locally. Can you expand on "the function that is being invoked on server object can be acquired as a string and pass it to server"?

Comment: @stuartd Hm.. OK here is what i ment. I didn't know that in the client side code a function definition named `newContosoChatMessage` existed few minutes ago.  I thought when i invoke a function in `server` object, It is somehow possible to get the name of the function and do something else with that name. for a pseudo code example, `server.onFunctionInvoked = function(funcName, args) {}`. Is this somehow possible to do javascript?

Comment: maybe you can look into something like http://docs.apigee.com/api-services/content/flow-configurations expand implementing api proxies > flows > configuring flows it said something like `Attach a JavaScript policy to a Conditional Flow of the ProxyEndpoint to execute JavaScript code to process the request` not sure if that is what you want though.

Comment: If you [use a manual client proxy](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#manualproxy), then you can change the code as you like.